# Amount of rows that contain a specific word in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame in which each row represents a customer message. I want a data frame with a Document Frequency - count the number of documents that contain that word. How can I get that?

For example, I have this

```
DATAFRAME A

customer  message
A         hi i need help i want a card
B         i want a card
```

The output I want is:

```
DATAFRAME B
word  document_frequency
hi      1
i       2 --> 2 documents contain "i", regardless the times it appears in each document
need    1 
help    1
want    2
a       2
card    2
```

What I have so far is the tokenized messages and the frequency of each word considering each document (times the word appears in each document, not the number of documents contain that word).
The output of tokenized messages is like this:

```
0  [hi, i, need, help, i, want, a, card,]
1  [i, want, a, card]
```

And the frequency of each word is a data frame like this:

```
DATAFRAME C
word  frequency
hi      1
i       3 --> word "i" appears 3 times
need    1 
help    1
want    2
a       2
card    2
```

Comment: Why ``i`` is only 2  regardless the times it appears ?

Comment: It appears in 2 documents. That's what I want

Answer (score 2):

From your original DataFrame, set the index, split the strings, explode and reset the index. This splits each word into its own cell, and the index manipulation makes it so we maintain the `'customer'` it was attached with.

`drop_duplicates` so words are only counted once within each `'customer'` and `groupby` + `size` to count the documents.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'customer': ['A', 'B'], 
                   'message': ['hi i need help i want a card', 'i want a card']})
```

---

```
(df.set_index('customer')['message'].str.split().explode()
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates()
   .groupby('message').size()
)

message
a       2
card    2
help    1
hi      1
i       2
need    1
want    2
dtype: int64
```

---

If you start from that Series, `s`, of lists with tokens, then do: `s.explode().reset_index()...`

Comment: it returns "'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'"

Comment: @RenataBiaggi you must be using an older version of `pandas`. That method was added in `0.25` so if you can, I suggest you update to a more recent version (currently it's at `1.0.4`). If that's not possible for whatever reason then you can look to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe for a workaround in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `collections.Counter` for something like this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from collections import Counter

df = DataFrame([{'customer': 'A', 'message': 'hi i need help i want a card'}, {'customer': 'B', 'message': 'i want a card'}])
#   customer                       message
# 0        A  hi i need help i want a card
# 1        B                 i want a card
counter = Counter()
for row in df['message']:
    counter.update(row.split())
print(counter)
# Counter({'i': 3, 'want': 2, 'a': 2, 'card': 2, 'hi': 1, 'need': 1, 'help': 1})
```

If you want to be able to do it case-insensitively, you can throw a `.lower()` in there between `row` and `.split()`.

Comment: This one is giving me what I already have, which I called Dataframe C. What I want is Dataframe B

Answer (score 0):

This would be the python 101 looping answer without using some of the more powerful pandas functions.

```
df['word'] = df['message'].str.split(' ')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'word' :[]})
word_list = []
for sentence in df['word']:
    for word in sentence:
        word_list.append(word)
df1['word'] = word_list
C = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('word')['word'].count()).rename({'word' : 'document_frequency'}, axis=1).reset_index()
C
```

Ouput:

```
    word    document_frequency
0   a       2
1   card    2
2   help    1
3   hi      1
4   i       3
5   need    1
6   want    2
```

Comment: This one is giving me what I already have, which I called Dataframe C. What I want is Dataframe B

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to see if a word is in a row and `sum`

```
res = df['message'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ').sum()
print (res)
a       2
card    2
help    1
hi      1
i       2
need    1
want    2
dtype: int64
```